# Why can't I copy this iTunes folder on Windows XP?: "Cannot copy file or folder: Cannot copy file:"

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, itunes

I'm moving an iTunes library for a friend from a XP computer to a new Dell. I've made sure to consolidate the library and make sure that nothing is read only (suggested online, don't know why that would affect it), but it still gives me this error every time I try to copy the folder onto an external hard drive:

> **Cannot copy file or folder** Cannot copy file:

*(The bold text is the title of the window.)* It doesn't even give me a full error message! I find this a really odd error that I cannot copy the file.

The external hard drive IIRC has a 4GB limit, but I've tried copying to the desktop and making a copy in the same folder to no avail. What could be causing this issue?

Comment: I will try to do some looking. But, I think you should try checking with iTunes or Windows (the former to see if others have had this problem and the latter to see if this is a common issue on the Microsoft end).

Comment: @L.B. just figured it out, working on am answer right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably isn't common, but I found that one of the folders full of music had a very long name. After renaming it to something shorter, Windows happily copied the content.

I'm curious how I even created the file that way in the first way. It seems odd that it couldn't copy something that I originally put in there. It might not have been length, as the name seemed to have excess whitespace, so I don't know what happened. I find it very odd that Windows couldn't produce a proper error.